# Wordpress update 5.0.2 removed WPBakery plugin templates

Tags: php, wordpress

I've come to this site after much research. After updating my wordpress site to 5.0.2 yesterday many different issues have risen on my site. I've been developing websites for the past six years and just recently (one week ago) moved to wordpress. I have been using this plugin known as WPBakery Page Builder to create my pages due to its ease and simplicity. My site has over 100 pages and the page builder really helps me with importing templates and different slides easily into multiple pages.

After updating Wordpress to the newest version, a new built-in page builder was added. This page builder is raw code and does not show any of my templates previously in WPBakery. As well as, it removed all my WPBakery templates. Every page now shows nothing in WPBakery and I'm trying to figure out how to restore all of this information.

I have tried restoring the older version of wordpress which did not work, currently I'm installing the latest back-up which was three days ago but its very outdated and is 5GB so is going to take all day. Other issues that have risen with this update include many icons disappearing (turned into blank squares) as well as a lot of random code has appeared throughout the site.
I have not touched the footer since creating the website and right after the wordpress update it turned to this:
[new-footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Aghm.png)

From this: [old-footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAvDI.png)

I understand how this site works and I probably won't receive any help but I have no where else to turn and if anyone can please help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the classic editor plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ That may help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which version are you using? WP Bakery added Gutenberg support to version 5.5.

Comment: @DanW. I will try this now

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo I'm using version 5.5.4

Comment: You could put up a "we're doing some maintenance" page while you restore your 5GB backup. There are plugins for that. Not an ideal solution but at least your visitors won't be seeing a broken site.

Comment: @DanW. Installing Classic Editor has seemed to fix the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Installing Classic Editor has fixed the issue! WPBakery templates are now back and the random code found throughout the website has disappeared.

Credit to @Dan W.